# How display multiple rows in a table with one row in another table after some calculations

Tags: mysql, select, left-join, multiple-tables

I have two tables. Table "user" contains user_id, user_name. Table "Transactions" contains user_id, transactions

Eg:
TABLE USER:

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | user_name |
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | Ram       |
| 2       | John      |
+---------+-----------+
```

TABLE Transactions

```
+---------+---------+--------------+
| user_id | type    | transactions |
+---------+---------+--------------+
| 1       | credit  | 500          |
| 1       | debit   | 300          |
| 2       | credit  | 250          |
| 1       | credit  | 450          |
| 2       | credit  | 100          |
| 1       | debit   | 250          |
| 2       | debit   | 50           |
+---------+---------+--------------+
```

I want to display the result by adding all credit amount and deduct all debit amount as shown below:

```
+-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| user_name | Total Credit | Total debit | Grand Total |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| Ram       | 950          | 550         | 400         |
| John      | 350          | 50          | 300         |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Forgot to format my question neatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
    u.user_name, 
    SUM(IF(t.type = 'credit', t.transactions, 0)) AS totalcredit,
    SUM(IF(t.type = 'debit', t.transactions, 0)) AS totaldebit,
    SUM(IF(t.type = 'credit', -1, 1) * t.transactions) AS total
FROM
    transactions t
INNER JOIN
    users u
ON
    u.user_id = t.user_id
GROUP BY
    u.user_name
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to name both the table and one of its fields "transactions"

Comment: I tested your code.But...I want to display all usernames even if they dont have any entry in transactions table. Could you please help

Comment: Just modified the answer of Nedret Recep with LEFT JOIN and reversed "transactions" and "users" order
   

    SELECT
            u.user_name, 
            SUM(IF(t.type = 'credit', t.transactions, 0)) AS totalcredit,
            SUM(IF(t.type = 'debit', t.transactions, 0)) AS totaldebit,
            SUM(IF(t.type = 'credit', -1, 1) * t.transactions) AS total
        FROM
            users u
        LEFT JOIN
            transactions t
        ON
            u.user_id = t.user_id
        GROUP BY
            u.user_name

Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 2):

As always, there's more than one way of skinning the cat!:

```
SELECT u.user_name, t2.TotCredit, t1.TotDebit, (t2.TotCredit-t1.TotDebit) AS "GrandTotal"     
  FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(transactions) AS "TotCredit" FROM transactiONs WHERE Type='Credit'GROUP BY user_id) AS t2     
LEFT OUTER JOIN      
    (SELECT user_id, SUM(transactions) AS "TotDebit" FROM transactiONs WHERE Type='Debit'GROUP BY user_id) AS t1     
  ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id     
LEFT OUTER JOIN      
    (SELECT user_name,user_id FROM user GROUP BY user_name) AS u     
  ON u.user_id = t2.user_id     

GROUP BY t2.user_id     
ORDER BY t2.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
SELECT u.user_name,
     SUM((IF(c.type = "credit", c.transactions, (0)))) AS total_credit,
     SUM((IF(c.type = "debit", c.transactions, (0)))) AS total_debit,
     SUM(IF(c.type = "credit", c.transactions, (0 - c.transactions))) AS grand_total
FROM
  credit_debit AS c
INNER JOIN user_details AS u
  ON c.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY
  u.user_id
```

Assume that only debit and credit type will be there, if any other types will come, then you need to change the code.